# How to run ant build in jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, atg

Please look into the screenshot below

[image: SS]

[image: SS]

Am trying to execute in the batch command! what am I making a mistake?

```
set DYNAMO_HOME=C:/ATG/ATG11.3.2/home
echo DYNAMO_HOME
D:/Users/aswad/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.15-bin/apache-ant-1.9.15/bin/ant build-atg-ear
```

Comment: java.exe is not recognized... Missing JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Type `java -version` on the command prompt and let us know the output.

Answer (score 0):

The build is failed due to - 'java.exe' in not recognised.
To solve this you need to add 'bin' folder of Java installation directory to 'PATH' environment variable. e.g. if Java is installed at C:/Java then there need to be an entry 'C:/Java/bin' in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run Ant as part of a Windows batch script. Instead, use the Jenkins plugin that is dedicated to this task. Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Available` and search for `Ant Plugin`.

After it's installed, go back to your job configuration and select a new build step `Invoke Ant`.